# Is there any reference which tells media/government of Pakistan or India don't show actual facts whenever there are ceasefire violations on LOC?

Tags: government, india, media, pakistan, kashmir

Every time I read any Indian newspaper or online news about ceasefire violation on LOC (Line of Control), I read "Pakistani troops violated the ceasefire and Indian troops responded accordingly".

I literally found no news in my life so far that India violated the ceasefire violation and Pakistan responded accordingly.

So I feel it is because of the government or media, who only shows half truth. But I don't have any proof for it.

But I sure do have genuine doubts.

So I feel, on both sides, media or government show only half truth.

How come it is possible that every time only Pakistan violated ceasefire on LOC in last 70 years? It seems entirely fiction.

Is there any reference which tells media/government of Pakistan or India don't show actual facts whenever there are ceasefire violations on LOC?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you'll find a single reference that will accurately cover all ceasefire violations. It's a large area and I don't think there are neutral observers who have direct access to the entire area. In the past there was a UN mission, [United Nations India-Pakistan Observation Mission (UNIPOM)](https://peacekeeping.un.org/mission/past/unipombackgr.html), which was tasked with observing the ceasefire. That mission ended over 50 years ago.

The best way to follow the conflict is to consider media reports from both sides of the conflict. I found a website, indopakconflictmonitor.org (IPCM), which claims to be:

> an independent research initiative to monitor ceasefire violations, conflict patterns, and escalation dynamics between India and Pakistan.

Looking at [the team behind the project](http://indopakconflictmonitor.org/team.php) it seems to be run mostly from New Delhi, India. Nevertheless, [their methodology](http://indopakconflictmonitor.org/methodology.php) aims to find all cease fire violations (CFVs) that are publicly reported (e.g. in news reports and from Twitter feeds of military organisations in the conflict).

Their list of CFVs, further divided by year, can be found [here](http://indopakconflictmonitor.org/cfv.php). As they say on [their methodology page](http://indopakconflictmonitor.org/methodology.php), it's not a complete account because not every incident is reported publicly:

> However, it should be noted that not all CFVs get reported in the press; since the reporting of the CFVs is bound to be lower than the actual occurrences of violations, the number of CFVs listed in the project’s datasets is significantly lower than the number of CFVs accounted for in the records.

That measures up with [their data for 2019](http://indopakconflictmonitor.org/yearwise_cfv.php?year=2019). They link to official data where both the Indian and Pakistani side claim about 3000 CFVs were perpetrated by the other side (in 2019 alone). The IPCM data links to about 200 incidents for that year (both sides combined).

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a lot of reports past 2019. Four incidents were [reported for 2020](http://indopakconflictmonitor.org/yearwise_cfv.php?year=2020) though that link doesn't seem to be available on their website (but you can query it by changing the URL).

In March of 2021 there were [reports of a ceasefire pact](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2021/3/9/will-the-india-pakistan-ceasefire-pact-along-kashmir-border-hold). I am not sure if that pact still stands, but the monitor does not show any new data for this year.

In any case, I think these sorts of monitors (there may be others if the IPCM is no longer maintained) that provide a timeline of events as they are reported (even if not verified) are a good start to get familiar with what's happening. Of course the lack of verification means there may be false reports in the data, but that's not something that can be overcome easily.

Comment: I have to apologize. I made a blunder in question. I confused LOC with POK. But I meant LOC actually. I have edited my question. You may want to edit answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think a narrow focus on who broke the ceasefire will miss the point of understanding the conflict. India have the upper hand in the region and can achieve everything with oppression (if the population allowed it.)

For the perspective from Pakistan then I think the go-to media source about the conflict is dawn.com. (A well established newspaper). Then you can combine it with the sources you have and try to get a broader unbiased view of the conflict.

Comment: Upper hand in what region?

Comment: I have to apologize. I made a blunder in question. I confused LOC with POK. But I meant LOC actually. I have edited my question. You may want to edit answer.

Comment: Dawn is a Pakistani newspaper that uncritically publishes reams of accusations originating from their own gov't, like blaming India for any and all terrorist activity in Pakistan, including that of the TTP ("Pakistani Taliban"). A good example: https://www.dawn.com/news/1590333