# Is there an overview of battles between the Afghan Army and Taliban forces during the Resolute Support Mission (2015-2021)?

Tags: military, armed-conflict, reference-request, afghanistan, taliban

According to the Wikipedia page on [the Resolute Support Mission (RSM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolute_Support_Mission):

> Resolute Support Mission or Operation Resolute Support was a NATO-led train, advise and assist mission consisting of about 7,772 coalition forces in Afghanistan, which began on January 1, 2015. It was a follow-on mission to the International Security Assistance Force (ISAF) which was completed on December 28, 2014.

[According to NATO](https://www.nato.int/cps/en/natohq/topics_8189.htm), this mission was a non-combat mission (click on 'Resolute Support Mission' to view the following background quote):

> Launched on 1 January 2015, the Resolute Support Mission (RSM) focused primarily on training, advice and assistance activities at the security-related ministries, in the country's institutions and among the senior ranks of the army and police.
>
> The non-combat mission performed supporting functions in several areas. These included operational planning; budgetary development; force generation process; management and development of personnel; logistical sustainment; and civilian oversight to ensure the Afghan national defence and security forces and institutions act in accordance with the rule of law and good governance.

During the RSM, the US military provided air support to Afghan forces fighting the Taliban. According to [the New York Times on May 6th, 2021](https://www.nytimes.com/2021/05/06/us/politics/afghanistan-withdrawal-biden-milley-austin.html):

> The United States has continued limited air support to Afghan national security forces in recent days, launching a half-dozen airstrikes as Taliban fighters stepped up an offensive in the country’s south before the full withdrawal of American troops ordered by President Biden.
>
> Even so, Afghan ground commanders are asking for more help from American warplanes, exposing a stark reality of the war there: Even in the twilight days of the American involvement, the Afghan dependency on U.S. pilots and warplanes as backup is unquestionable.
>
> The Pentagon is now weighing how it will wean Afghan security forces from their dependency, something that it has failed to do since 2015, when the United States formally ended its combat mission in the country.

During RSM it seems the Afghan Army was the primary ground force fighting against Taliban forces. With [the Afghan Army surrendering to Taliban forces so quickly after the US withdrawal](https://www.dw.com/en/why-the-afghan-army-folded-to-the-taliban/a-58889507), I'm wondering if there's any data about battles between the Afghan military and the Taliban.

On paper at least, it seems the US withdrawal hasn't changed much. Since 2015 the US-led coalition supports the Afghans primarily through air support, not by running point on the ground. The US also pledged late July 2021 that it would continue providing air support to Afghan forces, according to [Reuters](https://www.reuters.com/world/asia-pacific/us-offers-further-air-support-afghan-troops-amid-taliban-offensive-2021-07-25/):

> KABUL, July 25 (Reuters) - The United States will to continue to carry out airstrikes to support Afghan forces facing attack from the insurgent Taliban, a regional U.S. commander said on Sunday as U.S. and other international forces have drawn down troops in Afghanistan.

To better understand the situation, I'm asking if there's any data (a timeline maybe) of battles between the Afghan military (including ones with foreign support of any kind) and the Taliban during RSM (2015-2021).

Comment: I upvoted, but an "overview of battles" in an insurgency is probably better measured in ground control gained/lost, because there were probably not huge set-piece battles that mattered (until this past month or so). There's an AP article from April that the war was apparently/already not going in the Kabul government's favor https://apnews.com/article/taliban-middle-east-3ef479b1de676f00dd16dc8dcf6f4d0e

Comment: @Fizz yea, I'm not sure if it's a reasonable request. I figure there must be some record keeping, maybe the coalition forces have a (public) record of the air strikes where they helped ANA on the ground (with some additional situation reports). Perhaps there's some academic effort to collect news reports.

Comment: And in something reminiscent of Vietnam, the US apparently did its best to obfuscate that its ally was losing: the published metrics kept changing to make comparisons over time difficult or impossible... Likewise was strength of the enemy/Taliban not publicly tracked since 2019 https://www.npr.org/2019/05/01/719018027/the-u-s-public-will-no-longer-have-a-key-data-point-about-afghanistan-war

Comment: However "monthly attacks" by the Taliban were apparently still tracked post 2019 so this might be a measure to look at. (As Ho Chi Minh said: an insurgency that is not attacking is losing.)

Comment: Afghan security forces losses have also been classified https://www.militarytimes.com/news/your-military/2019/05/01/classified-or-nonexistent-tracking-taliban-control-goes-dark-as-focus-shifts-to-getting-out/ So I guess we won't know much until such stuff is declassified...

Comment: This is unanswerable.   Whilst there is data for every logged TIC event (Troops in Contact) it will certainly not be available to any civilian wishing to answer this question.

Comment: @Venture2099 perhaps not a complete record but even a partial record (based on journalism on the ground, press releases, etc.) would answer the question. Let's look at it this way: if the allied forces have not taken the lead on the ground and the ANA has, then there must be some public record of that (even if it's just eye-witness accounts).

Comment: For which Provinces?  Those that were supported purely by the USA?   The record you are talking about is gargantuan.  Do you count contact against warlords, private militias, Al Qaeda or drug dealers?  For instance - some of the primary resistance in Nimruz was from heavily armed and organised criminals far removed from the Taliban.  AQ fighters would often fight separate to the Taliban, sometimes even against them.

Comment: @Venture2099 I've currently phrased it to focus on the Taliban. Nevertheless, I asked the question to get an understanding of how capable the ANA was during the RSM. So even if the enemy is not specified or one of those other groups then it would help get an understanding of their battlefield capabilities (depending on how specific the description of the engagement is).

Comment: @Venture2099 the way I see it, there's been a 5 year NATO mission to train Afghan troops and now that NATO is pulling out we see the Afghans getting a lot of flack for withdrawing so soon, with repatriation efforts still ongoing. Given the Afghan forces seem to have been the primary force on the ground for 5 years now, I don't think it's an unreasonable question ask about their battlefield capabilities during those years.

Comment: That is not the question you asked. If you are asking for an assessment of the Afghan National Army that can be provided objectively.  A list of their TiC events is not a question that can be answered.

Comment: @Venture2099 for the reasons Fizz indicated, I'm not really interested in 'objective assessments' by those who trained the forces. Feel free to ask that question yourself, I think it would be on-topic. :)

Comment: ...so your question is that you want others to provide you classified data so that YOU can make an assessment as to the capabilities of the Afghan National Army?  Failing complete data you will be happy with cobbled together unclassified data from unreliable sources and media reports and from that data you wish to determine the effectiveness of the ANA.   That must be off topic.  The fact that the ANA have crumbled is not evidence enough, you are hoping for something else?

Comment: @Venture2099 no, I'm asking for public data. I image there might be [something like my answer here about the Indian Pakistan conflict](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/66364). Of course it's possible that answer might not exist, but there's a chance it's out there. Why do you think that's off-topic?

Comment: That question was closed.  And rightly so.  Your use of quotation marks around the word "objective assessment" also indicated that this question is a vehicle for you to argue or otherwise debate some aspect of Afghanistan rather than seeking a genuine answer.

Comment: @Venture2099 no, I'm asking for any answer that shows performance in battle. I'm not interested in non-combat assessments (e.g. performance in target practice or in interviews). That doesn't make it a bad-faith effort, I'm happy with whatever answer sheds some light on actual performance (even if they come from NATO forces, but as you say they're probably not publicly available). Feel free to argue that it's a bad faith question on meta, but I'm afraid this comment exchange isn't productive.

Comment: I have no doubt you are about to wield your diamond but at present, your question in the comments is not even close to the question you have asked above.  You have also said you will not accept NATO assessments of the Afghan National Army (no one mentioned target practice..not sure where you got that from).  Your reference for the validity of this question was a question that was closed.    What specifically are you asking for?

Comment: @Venture2099 any assessment based on performance in battle would be a (partial) answer to the question. When you said assessments I assumed you meant some assessment in a training situation, I'm hesitant about accepting that because it may not be indicative about real-world performance.

Answer (score -1):

No. There is no meaningful timeline of battles between the Afghan National Army and the Taliban that can be accessed by members of the public. Even if such a timeline existed it would not be indicative of ANA performance given the myriad other factors including fixed wing and rotary support, ISTAR assets and direct combat support from NATO troops.

Also, the ANA were often rotated into different provinces in order to break familial or tribal links to the local area and to try and prevent corruption and green on blue attacks.

There are countless media reports of individual combat events which a diligent researcher may wish to aggregate into a single record but it would not be comprehensive.

There are also many reports published in open source journals, within parliamentary records and within NATO documents regarding the training and combat performance of the Afghan Security Forces.    Reports include vignettes, interviews and direct testimony of their conduct under fire.

For instance: Lieutenant Colonel Gavin Keating, 'Living in the Twilight Zone: Advising the Afghan National Army at the Corps Level', Australian Army Journal, Vol. VIII, No. 3, Summer 2011.

Comment: Thanks. I think it would be great if you can include one excerpt of such publicly available direct testimony or combat performance assessment. I'll wait a few more days to see if someone can find such a 'diligent researcher' who has already made an aggregate record. If not and you include such a quote then I'm happy to accept a single data point as an answer. :)

Comment: You need to avoid or explain the jargon (rotary wing, ISTAR, green on blue, etc.)

Comment: No, I don't.  If people are asking for combat reports then some familiarity with these terms must exist otherwise combat reports would be near-useless.